# How to perform the Elliptic Curve calculation in the following example?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic

> [image: part 1]
>
> [image: part 2]

can someone show me the working how to get (10,6) what i am getting is (10,5) for 3P

Comment: I can confirm the results of $2P$ and $3P$ from the picture.

Comment: As for your calculations not working, I suggest writing down how you came to $(10,5)$ for $3P$.

Comment: is there a way i can insert a pic here

Comment: i did the calculation of it on a paper i have taken a pic how can i show you the working

Comment: (6,3) (5,1)
(1-3)(5-6)^1 mod 17=15 
x3=152 -5-6 mod 17=10
y3=15(6-10)-3 mod17=5

Comment: plz help really need it

Comment: SEJPM 41 you there

Comment: TL;DR: Your formula for computing $y_3$ is off.

Comment: Please try and use a title as specific as possible to your problem, without it other visitors cannot quickly see what the Q/A is about. I've fixed the title for now.

Answer (score 2):

So let's take a closer look at this:

- Your field is $K=\mathbb F_{17}$.
- Your elliptic curve over this field has the equation $y^2=x^3+2x+2$
- Your one point is $(5,1)$
- Your other point is $(6,3)$

As a reference, I'm taking [the explicit formula from the database](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw.html).

1. You calculate $K\ni s=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=2$
2. Then you calculate $K\ni x_3=s^2-x_1-x_2=10$
3. Finally you calculate $K\ni y_3=(2x_1+x_2)s-s^3-y_1=6$

Thus the result is $(10,6)$ as expected.

---

In Sage-Code this would look like this:

```
K=GF(17)
a=K(2)
# ... assign x1,x2,y1,y2 here the same way as a
s=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
x3=s*s-x1-x2
y3=(2*x1+x2)*s-s^3-y1
```